# How to get an offset in RecyclerView ItemDecorator

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have written two `ItemDecorator`'s for `RecyclerView`. Each adds some top offset in `getItemOffsets()`. Let's say:

- First decorator adds 20dp top offset
- Second decrator adds 30dp top offset

Now, when I add both of them to `RecyclerView`, each item is correctly offsetted by 50dp, that's good.

But here comes the question: 
How do I get this offset in `onDraw`/`onDrawOver`?

Usually decorators draw their stuff by traversing `parent.getChildAt(i)` stuff and getting `child.getTop()` for example to draw above child view of `RecyclerView`.

But in this case, doing so would mix up the drawing of other decorator, because it would also use `child.getTop()`.

So at the moment it seems like both decorators need to know about each other and each other's height.

Am I missing something here? I hope I am.

**EDIT:** *I reported an issue to Android issue tracker and it seems this will be worked on. Star it to keep track of progress:* https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195746

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*tl;dr* No you are not missing anything. But you can get the values needed in `getItemOffsets`, albeit it seems a little bit dirty to me.

Basically there is only *one* option of getting the decorated height other than managing decorations yourself: `LayoutManager.getDecoratedTop();`

**onDraw**

In `onDraw` you get the whole canvas of the recyclerView, `c.getClipBounds()` does not hold any information. Albeit the javadoc of adding decorations says that decorations should just draw withing *their* bounds.

Also, getting `parent.getLayoutManager().getDecoratedTop()` will give you the same values in every decoration, since it's already too late here, those values are for layouting purposes.

We are too late, layouting is done and we missed it.

**getItemOffsets**

> Please note that I tested the following with a `LinearLayoutManager` and it might as well not work with the others (Most definitely not with most custom ones). Since I am relying on measuring happening between those calls, which is not documented, the given solution might break with some future version.

I just felt I needed that disclaimer. I found a working solution (watch the `mOffset`):

```
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    mOffset = parent.getLayoutManager().getTopDecorationHeight(view);
    outRect.set(0, 10, 0, 0);
}
```

This works, because the recyclerview, when calculating the total inset of the child, is [updating the views package local LayoutParams variable](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java#RecyclerView.getItemDecorInsetsForChild%28android.view.View%29). While we cannot access the layout parameter variable itself, calling getTopDecorationHeight actually uses the (currently) dirty inset, giving us the proper value.
Hence, you can get the offset of the previous decorations before applying your own!

To apply it, just remove the other decorations offset when drawing your decoration:

```
c.drawRect(child.getLeft() + child.getTranslationX(),
        mOffset + layoutManager.getDecoratedTop(child) + child.getTranslationY(),
        child.getRight() + child.getTranslationX(),
        child.getBottom() + child.getTranslationY(), paint);
```

This will actually apply the other decorations offset, then draw your own from the *correct* top.

**Some Problems**

This is now a basic, working solution for the *default usecase*. **BUT**. If you have different offsets depending on the item VIEW_TYPE or the adapter position things get tricky.

You will either duplicate your logic and keep various offsets for various view types or you have to store / retrieve the offset for every view or viewtype.

To do so, you could either add some custom tag with `view.setTag(key, object)` or doing something similar with the `RecyclerView.State` object that's getting passed around.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer! This will do for now, although I must add that the current situation is not very well. I'll need to find some time to file an issue in Android Issue tracker for this.

Comment: @dimsuz I feel really good about the current solution, and think it might work. if you do file an issue, please supply me the link! thanks :)

Comment: That `view.setTag()` hint was something that really helped me to draw differently depending on View Type, View Position etc. Great tip!